# Margin detection is acting weird

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a game, and I'm currently working on making a sprite move around. I need to make sure that it can't go outside a certain div. I've attempted to create a function that checks whether the top or left distance is smaller than 0px, but it doesn't work very well.

Issues:

1) The sprite is stopping well inside the border, which is not where it's supposed to stop.

2) Instead of stopping animation once the sprite has reached the edge, the sprite slows down before stopping completely. The actual place where it stops is sometimes a few pixels higher or lower.

3) The sprite gets stuck once it reaches a certain place, and it can't get away.

Here is the main function:

```
var cstop = false;
    function colCheck() {
        if (
            (char.css("top")<"0px") ||
            (char.css("left")<"0px") ||
            (char.css("top")>"500px") ||
            (char.css("left")>"800px")
        )
        {
            cstop = true;
        }
    };
```

The cstop variable is then checked whenever an arrow key is pressed.

I've played around with the code, but I can't seem to figure out why it's not working like I want it to.
jsFiddle with relevant code: http://jsfiddle.net/VYkbR/13/

Comment: You can't compare strings like that with '<' and '>'. They are strings, not numbers.

Comment: Not to mention you would need to revise your logic. You don't want the player to get permanently stuck if two sides of the character are touching two sides of the wall.

Comment: @Brian But won't .css("top") return the value of top? Would the value be a string too? Sorry if I'm missing something here, I'm still pretty new to javascript.

Comment: @remyabel Why exactly would the player get stuck? I probably messed up a lot of the logic, but I'm not sure what's causing each issue.

Comment: @user2748569 yeah, css() returns strings.

Answer (score 0):

You might wan't to replace the `px` and then compare, like this.

```
var left = (+ char.css("left").replace('px', ''));
```

then do

```
if(left < 0) {
    // code here..
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, I'll try it. One thing - won't the result still be a string?

Comment: No the `+` sign converts a string to a number only if the string contains only numbers,

Comment: Oh, that's great - I haven't seen that before.